# SQL pagination duplicates with ordering by non-unique value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with 500 items about. I want to get all of items but in five different queries (5 pages). These items will need be sorted by non-unique field "name". 
When i try to use these query i have duplicates in the edges of pages:

```
SELECT T.* 
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM Table
) T
ORDER BY "name"
OFFSET (n - 1)*100 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
```

n — page number.

I know that i can add any unique value to ordering, but i don't want do that)

But when i changed my query, my problem was disappeared:

```
 SELECT T.* 
 FROM (
   SELECT *
   FROM Table 
   ORDER BY "name"
 ) T
 OFFSET (n - 1)*100 ROWS 
 FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
```

Why Ihave gotten ORACLE  behavior like these and which solution i can use?

Comment: Why the derived table at all? `SELECT *
  FROM Table 
ORDER BY "name"
OFFSET (n - 1)*100 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY` should work just fine

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name my column "name" has duplicates. Can i rely that ORACLE will order the result set in the same way in each query?

Comment: No, you can't. You need to include a tie-breaker in the `order by` for that. E.g. the primary key column(s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its only when you have a consistent result set for the recordset would you be able to paginate without overlaps.(You may be lucky if records doesnt overlap, but its not a guarantee that it will work all of the time)

So you need to order by something unique. In this case you can order by "Name","primary_key_fields" to achieve a consistent results for pagination

This is in general behaviour and not just about ORACLE database.

See an example in dbfiddle. Here in the first query i use offset=1 rows and fetch 10 rows only and ordering only by name. i get 10 records

```
select *
  from t
 order by name offset 1 rows fetch next 10 rows only
```

In the second query i use offset=11 rows and fetch 10 rows only. i get the same 10 records which should not have overlapped

```
select *
  from t
 order by name offset 11 rows fetch next 10 rows only
```

Now if were to use the order by name and the "primary key" i wouldnt get any overlaps

```
select *
  from t
 order by name,x offset 1 rows fetch next 10 rows only

select *
  from t
 order by name,x offset 11 rows fetch next 10 rows only
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=dc18bcfa3a73b177114b5e93979f2a44

Comment: Can you explain, what if i will use Oracle's ROWID instead my own unique column, will it be a correct solution?

Comment: But i use joining number of different tables

Comment: The term "primary key" is a word for unique combination of columns. If you have multiple joining tables you may order by some unique combination fields